# Spring Security filter, HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have done my RESTful Webservice along with the same project that implements Admin panel application. The problem i face is that the POST request comes to the application gets converted to GET.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When the filter got commented everything works as normal.

Other GET requests are having no problem in both case when filter is present or not.

error i get is

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

How can i override Spring security filter for my Web service ?

Answer (score 0):

solved

Just un-comment any resource if you don't want authentication to be done on them

@ spring security.xml file add the following.

```
<http pattern="/webservice/**" security="none"/>
```